# Is there a way to include either a user input prompt or a time.sleep() function within a key value pair of a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input, time

I am working on a Python text RPG, and I'm using dictionaries to give initial information to the player about the area they're visiting. (see code for example). When the player types 'look' or 'examine,' I want the console to print out what I have in the value of the EXAMINATION key. What I'd like to have it do is print a section of text at a time, and either wait for the player to hit enter before continuing or at least wait a couple of seconds before printing the next block. Is there a way to achieve this? Perhaps I'm coming at this from the wrong direction?

```
import time
import sys

def prompt():
    print("\n" + "=========================")
    print("What would you like to do?")
    player_action = input("> ")
    acceptable_actions = ['move', 'go', 'travel', 'walk', 'quit', 'examine', 'inspect', 'interact', 'look']
    while player_action.lower() not in acceptable_actions:
        print("Unknown action, try again.\n")
        player_action = input("> ")
    if player_action.lower() == 'quit':
        sys.exit()
    elif player_action.lower() in ['move', 'go', 'travel', 'walk']:
        player_move(player_action.lower())
    elif player_action.lower() in ['examine', 'inspect', 'interact', 'look']:
        player_examine(player_action.lower())

def player_examine(player_action):
    if zonemap[myPlayer.location][SOLVED]:
        print("There's nothing more here to examine.")
    elif zonemap[myPlayer.location][EXAMINATION]:
        slowprint(zonemap[myPlayer.location][EXAMINATION])

ZONENAME = ''
DESCRIPTION = 'description'
EXAMINATION = 'examine'
SOLVED = False
UP = 'up', 'north'
DOWN = 'down', 'south'
LEFT = 'left', 'west'
RIGHT = 'right', 'east'

zonemap = {
    'Fields': {
        ZONENAME: "Western Fields",
        DESCRIPTION: "A grassy field to the west of town.",
        EXAMINATION: "The grass in this field is extremely soft." + input("> ") + "The wind feels cool on your face." + time.sleep(2) + "The sun is beginning to set.",
        SOLVED: False,
        UP: "The Mountains",
        DOWN: "The Town",
        LEFT: "", 
        RIGHT: "The Ocean",
    },
```

When trying to use the time.sleep() method, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

When trying to use the input("> ") function, the text simply prints on without waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work because you are *immediately* calling the `input()` or `time.sleep()` functions as you build the dictionary. `time.sleep()`, for example, returns `None` and that's why you get your error.

You need to call those functions *later on*, when you retrieved the value from the dictionary and actually want to 'slow print' the description.

You can do so in loads of different ways. You could

- use a sequence (such as a list or a tuple) of strings instead of a single string, and have your `slowprint()` function accept a sequence and pause after printing each element.
- use a sequence of strings and mix in special values that `slowprint()` looks for to do different things, like sleeping or asking for input.
- Store a function in the dictionary, that you then call. Functions are objects too, just like strings. The function would handle all the printing and pausing.

E.g. storing a tuple of strings:

```
EXAMINATION: (
    "The grass in this field is extremely soft.",
    "The wind feels cool on your face.",
    "The sun is beginning to set.",
)
```

then have your `slowprint()` function handle that:

```
def slowprint(lines):
    """Print each line with a pause in between"""
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        input("> ")   # or use time.sleep(2), or some other technique
```

The second option, to insert special values, gives you the most power to delegate all sorts of extra functionality to other code. You'd need to test for the type of object in the sequence, but this would let you insert arbitrary actions in your examination description. Like the difference between sleeping and asking for the user to hit a key:

```
class ExaminationAction:
    def do_action(self):
        # the default is to do nothing
        return

class Sleep(ExaminationAction):
    def __init__(self, duration):
        self.duration = duration

    def do_action(self):
        time.sleep(self.duration)

class Prompt(ExaminationAction):
    def __init__(self, prompt):
        self.prompt = prompt

    def do_action(self):
        return input(self.prompt)
```

and have the `slowprint()` function look for these instances:

```
def slowprint(examine_lines):
    for action_or_line in examine_lines:
        if isinstance(action_or_line, ExamineAction):
            # special action, execute it
            action_or_line.do_action()
        else:
            # string, print it
            print(action_or_line)
```

You can make any number such actions; the point is that they all subclass `ExamineAction` so can be distinguished from plain strings. Put them into your sequence for the `EXAMINATION` key:

```
EXAMINATION: (
    "The grass in this field is extremely soft.",
    Prompt("> "),
    "The wind feels cool on your face.",
    Sleep(2),
    "The sun is beginning to set.",
)
```

The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn, I will give these a try and see which works the best for me.